# Join no Laravel 5.x em duas tabelas?

Tags: php, laravel

Eu tenho duas tabelas que já estão relacionadas no `MySQL` e utilizo `Laravel`, já estou persistindo as informações no banco. Quando eu gravo uma noticia, ela já é atribuída ao autor normalmente (tabelas `autor` e `news`).

Na hora de listar as `news`, eu fiz o seguinte método na `NewsControllers`

```
public function listar()
{
        $news= News::all();
        return view('listar')->with('news', $news);
}
```

Ai quando eu quero exibir elas nas views, eu faço

```
@foreach ($news $n)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $n->id}}</td>
        <td>{{ $n->conteudo}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

E tu funciona perfeitamente.

Minha dúvida seria, como exibir o nome do autor nessa listagem e naquele método listar?

#### [news]

```
id
titulo
conteudo
autor (FK com id de autores)
```

#### [autores]

```
id
nome
```

Comment: Eu coloquei uma resposta, mas, o que eu precisava era ver os dois models que você citou na sua pergunta, tem como coloca-los?

Comment: Mas a model dele é automatica, no meu saco

Comment: Ou como se chama isso, quando minha model tem apenas isso: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class News extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'news';
    public $timestamps = true;
}

Comment: esse á classe que herda do Eloquent para operações de CRUD (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE E DELETE) , só tem isso?

Comment: Sim, apenas isso!

Comment: qual é a classe de Autores?

Comment: Percebi que todas as suas perguntas possui respostas e que não foram aceita por você, seria legal @Roberta fazer isso, leia isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote por favor não deixe de aceitar as resposta se servirem para você!

Answer (score 3):

Para utilizar todos os recursos do [`Eloquent`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) deve adicionar as relação da seguinte forma:

```
<?php namespace App;     

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

   class News extends Model 
   {
        protected $table = 'news'; 
        public $timestamps = true; 
        public function autor()
        {       
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Autores', 'autor', 'id');      
        }
    }
```

---

No método do `controller` chame a relação com `with`:

```
public function listar()
{
    $news= News::with('autor')->get();
    return view('listar')->with('news', $news);
}
```

E na sua `view`:

```
@foreach ($news as $n)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$n->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$n->conteudo}}</td>
        <td>{{$n->autor->nome}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Se eu não tivesse relacionamento, esta forma serveria?

Comment: $news= News::with('autor')->get(); Ela se equievale ao método all()?

Comment: @Roberta isso tudo é com relacionamentos, se não tiver é só colocar, mas, como eu disse no comentário da pergunta tem como você colocar os dois `models` por favor?

Comment: `$news= News::with('autor')->get(); Ela se equievale ao método all()?` quando se está no builder o método é `get()`, que na verdade tem o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Como seria na view? <td>{{ $n->autor->nome}}</td> ??

Comment: @Roberta eu fiz uma outra edição, só precisa do layout da classe autores para saber se está certinho... se pode adicionar na pergunta?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::autor()

Comment: @Roberta eu precisa do layout das duas tabelas e das classes que você fez para elas para fazer o exemplo de acordo com sua realidade, por isso pode acontecer erros, veja com certeza se não viu a minha resposta porque esse método existi no meu exemplo ...

Answer (score 3):

Assim também funciona:

```
public function listar()
{
        $news= News::join('autor', 'news.autor', '=', 'autor.id')
            ->select('news.id', 'titulo', 'conteudo', 'nome')
            ->get();
        return view('listar')->with('news', $news);
}
```